# how to hide a UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a single page iOS app (Swift 4, Xcode 9). It has a UITableView and a UIDatePicker. When the app loads only the table is visible to the user - it takes up the whole screen. When the user clicks "show date picker" I want the table to disappear so that the date picker comes into view. But I can't figure out how to do that. The table does disappear when I set `tableView.isHidden = true`, but the screen just goes blank, the date picker doesn't become visible. What am I doing wrong?

(I know I could have a second view controller, a segue, etc, but I'm trying to keep it simple for now.)

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MyTable
//
//  Created by Parzival on 9/9/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Parzival. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // data for the table view cells
    let rowNames: [String] = ["foo", "bar", "show date picker"]

    // cell reuse id (cells that scroll out of view can be reused)
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    // hook this up from the storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        makeTable()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func makeTable() {
        // Register the table view cell class and its reuse id
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        // (optional) include this line if you want to remove the extra empty cell divider lines
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        // This view controller itself will provide the delegate methods and row data for the table view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.rowNames.count
    }

    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        // set the text from the data model
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.rowNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            tableView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would put the tableview and pickerview in a stackview and then just set the `isHidden` property of the picker as required. This will move the tableview up

Comment: Didn't about this stackview thing (total iOS n00b here). I'll look into it.

Comment: One thing to consider IMHO? "Show date picker" sounds like you want it to be presented *above* the table view. Disappearing tables seems (to me) to be poor UI based on user expectations. I all you want is to get a date to *use* with the table view, `present` a view (or view controller is you need logic behind the date being picked) over the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy solution. Put two views into a stackView. One is hidden, one is not.
constrain the stack view to the frame of parent View.

add one line code:  **datePicker.isHidden = false**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        tableView.isHidden = true
        datePicker.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is cool, but I'm trying to mimic the "Starts" and "Ends" table cells in the "New Event" screen of the Calendar app. Those two cells are next to each other at first, but when the user clicks the "Starts" row, a picker and another row slide into view. They disappear when the row is clicked again. How would you do that? I can't figure it out. Yet.

Comment: SwiftUI will come. Just do that way